# EAnnotation usage in ecore

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

Can anybody explain the usage of EAnnotation in ecore, in terms of its specific fields (i.e., 
    *Source*,
    *Details*,
    *EModel Element*,
    *Contents*, and 
    *References*). I looked at its API [documentation here](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/javadoc/2.4.2/org/eclipse/emf/ecore/EAnnotation.html#getReferences%28%29), but could not get that much from there.

I am looking for a kind of guideline to explain by example what are the purpose of having annotations with such fields in ecore.

Answer (score 6):

I asked this question in Eclipse EMF forum and [here is an answer](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1066382/).
There is also an answer to this question [here.](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t107460.html).

However, I briefly provide an answer to this question:
Generally EAnnotations are used in Ecore to encode any kind of information which is not captured by Ecore at first place. For example, they are used in [OCLInECore](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.ocl.doc%2Fhelp%2FOCLinEcoreTutorialExampleProject.html) to hold OCL constraints, or in [genmodel](http://dentrassi.de/my-projects/emf-genmodel-annotations/) to store code generation related information and etc.

**Source** is used to identify the type of annotation. It is usually populated with a URI, to uniquely identify the type of annotation.

**Details** is a set of (key,value) pairs to hold detailed information regarding this annotation. Actually this is the place annotation data are really stored.

The rest is (quoted from [here](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1066382/)):

**EModel Element** ,
"An EAnnotation is itself an EModelElement, so can also be annotated. It's not
often used, but would allow you to build a complex structure.."

**Contents** 
EAnnotations can contain arbitrary other objects. This is also not
often used, and if you do use it, you can't generate a normal
XyzPackageImpl but must ensure that the GenPackage specifies "Initialize
by Loading"..."

**References**.
"EAnnotations can refer to arbitrary other objects. This is also not
often used, and the same caveat applies and for the contents..."